# Move files under GCS with renaming

Tags: bash, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to write the following bash script which copies files from one GCS bucket to another with renaming options.

My input folder is `gs://test-rtt-integration/result/frd/*.orc`
and my destination folder is `gs://test-rtt-integration/recent_files/frd`

The  renaming of the copied file should be done based on the name provided from  `gs://test-rtt-integration/complex-files/TAN/recent_files/today/frd`
once the copy with renaming is done I need to clean `gs://test-rtt-integration/result/frd`

I tested the following commands, but they are not working properly

```
NAME = "$(gsutil ls gs://test-rtt-integration/complex-files/TAN/recent_files/today/frd)"
gsutil mv gs://test-rtt-integration/result/frd/*.orc   gs://test-rtt-integration/recent_files/frd/$NAME
gsutil rm -rf gs://test-rtt-integration/result/frd
```

( all .orc files and other files should be deleted)

But this is not working properly as I have to split the NAME based on / and get the last split , so if the result of split is called `SPLIT` , I  have to do `gsutil mv gs://test-rtt-integration/result/frd/*.orc   gs://test-rtt-integration/recent_files/frd/$SPLIT`

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little bit confusing. You say that you want to move files from one Google Cloud Storage bucket to another, but all the operations are made in one single bucket called `test-rtt-integration`.

However, as soon as you get the file location with the command `gsutil ls gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/folder` e.g. `gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/folder/[FILENAME].orc`, since the `gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/folder/` part is always the same for all the objects in the folder, just replace it with `null` and you will get only the object name at the end as `[FILENAME].orc` etc.

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I did a little bit of coding myself and I have created a bash script that:

- Gets the name of each object from `gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/from` bucket folder
- Copy all objects from `gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/from` bucket folder to the `gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/to/` bucket folder
- Delete all objects from `gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/from` bucket folder

Inside there are comments that explain how every operation works in details. If that is not exactly what you are looking for, you can get the basic idea of how that works and implement it in different way that will suit you better. I have tested the scrip myself in Google Cloud Shell and it is working. The [example code can be found in GitHub](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Bucket/move_files_bash.sh).